# What are possible reasons why iwconfig is not updating connection stats?

Tags: networking, wifi, proc

I use `iwconfig` to show me some information about my current internet connection like this

```
$ iwconfig
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"eduroam"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 06:0B:6B:2E:A7:80   
          Bit Rate=6 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=42/70  Signal level=-68 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:19522   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

In the past these information were updated each time I ran the command. Lately, the information remain the same from the beginning of the connection. The same applies to what I get via `cat /proc/net/wireless`. What may be the reason for this and how can I fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem.
My kernel is: Linux brilliant-laptop 4.0.4-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 22 03:05:23 UTC 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: And my card is RTL8187L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given by an update of the arch linux kernel to 4.1.2. Now it works again, thus it must have been something to do with the kernel version.